# Getting output from VB shell

Tags: vb.net, windows, shell, redirectstandardoutput

I have been searching around in the internet but still no luck on the results...

I am writing a short script to check server status, it is an external exe file, where you can normally run it using command shell by using:

```
theExe.exe /theSeverAddress
```

However, after it finishes running the command, a pause command is executed by the exe

```
Press Enter to continue . . .
```

This causes me a headache when trying to use VB to stream the results back as it will not stream... My current code is as follow:

```vb
Dim proc As New Process()
oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c theExe.exe " & theServerAddress)
oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
proc.StartInfo = oStartInfo
proc.Start()

Dim sOutput As String
Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = proc.StandardOutput
    sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
End Using
Console.WriteLine(sOutput)
```

Here is the weird thing...

- If I run this script, a black window (presumably it's the cmd?) appears, and the script stops at `sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()`. It will continue to run only if I close the black window. For this case, all data is streamed to the `sOutput`.
- If I add `oStartInfo.CraeteNoWindow = False` into the script, no black window appears, the script stops at `sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()`, and I need to kill the `cmd.exe` to get the script to continue to run. Again, all data is streamed to the `sOutput`.

However, I don't want to manually close the window / kill the task. Here comes the strange thing that I have observed:

- If I close the black window before the script stops at `sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()` (by stepping the code line by line), whether I close it manually by clicking the 'x' in the black window or using `Shell("cmd /c taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe")`, the script will continue to run, but only a part of the results is streamed to the `sOutput`...

It seems to me that, unless you have initiated the `oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()`, the streamed data will not be the full one; however, it will not stream unless the previous command has stopped...

Anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Does the exe have a command line key for unattended/quiet mode?

Comment: If not, you will have to pass at least a `vbCrLf` to the process' standardInput. `ReadToEnd ()` wont end until the stream is closed (app is closed).

Comment: @GSerg No, the exe does not have a command line for unattended mode in windows...
@Clijsters How to send the `vbCrLf` command to the process? How does it know when has reach the end before it send out the `vbCrLf` ?

Comment: To send something to the process, write it to `StandardInput`. To learn when, that would be when that "Press enter" appears. To learn when it appears you'd have to change how you read the standard input to at least line by line.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be slightly easier than I thought after fiddling around the code, not sure why it works, but somehow it works now... It seems that I have to kill `theExe.exe` instead of killing the `cmd.exe`...

```
Dim proc As New Process()
Dim oStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c theExe.exe " & sServer)
oStartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
oStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
oStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
proc.StartInfo = oStartInfo
proc.Start()

Dim sOutput As String

Shell("cmd /c taskkill /F /IM theExe.exe", AppWinStyle.Hide)

Using oStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = proc.StandardOutput
    sOutput = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
End Using

proc.Dispose()
```

Comment: That's a race condition. Sometimes you will have time to read the output, sometimes you won't.